# How to implement search assist in python-django using simple ajax apart from using backbone.js?

Tags: python, ajax, django, search

I'm trying to implement search assist in my django powered project and i dont have a clue how to do it.
I saw few examples using backbone.js but its beyond my level.
Is there any simple ajax function for this purpose?
Thanks

Comment: what is "search assist"?  If it's autocomplete jquery has a very easy to use plugin

Comment: Auto complete the search query by results from the database